# how it works whatsapp

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How does Whatsapp continue to receive notifications of received messages, even after you kill the app or restart the phone?

I am using an application that sends location coordinates, and it's for iOS, written in Swift.

My problem is that when I kill the app, the application stops sending coordinates. How I can make it restart automatically? For example, Whastapp, despite killing the app, if someone sends me a message, I receive the notification

I have also tried creating a widget app, but this is activated only when under the bar where the widget exists.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp continues receiving *PushNotifications*. These are sent by Web Server and the App need not be active for it.

Coming to your requirement, you can use options like *requestAlwaysAuthorization* (to keep App awake in background to be able to send notifications). *SignificantLocationChange*, *RegionMonitoringService*, *VisitService* (to relaunch you app in the background if terminated).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial. you need to have one developer account to use push notification. It's easy to implement.